# MS SQLServer Searching to see if a value is contained in other values

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I come from a background in PostgreSQL.

If I wanted to search all of the columns in all of the tables for any column name that contained "the" somewhere in the value, I would do this:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where column_name ilike '%the%'
```

This does not work in SQL Server 2008 R2, does anyone have any suggestions? I am running this query so far:

```
select t.name as table_name, c.name as column_name
from sys.tables as t
inner join
    sys.all_columns as c
on
    c.object_id = t.object_id

where t.name ilike '%the%'

order by c.name, t.name;
```

The where t.name ilike '%the%' is what makes the query fail with the following error message:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'ilike'.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ilike doesn't exist in sql server, you can use like instead.

Comment: Thank you, I just used lower(t.name) like '%the%'